# Position of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

How do i get the position of a modal UINavigationController on the iPad-Screen? I tried .view.frame, but i always get the coordinates 0,0. The size seems to be correct. I tried to get it in viewDidAppear, also in the completion block at the presentViewController.

Comment: In which method are you trying to do this? You should defer these sorts of references until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: (As aside, obviously view controllers don’t have a position. Only their views do. You may want to edit the title and text accordingly.)

Comment: A view controller doesn't have any position on screen. I'm sure you mean the view that the view controller manages, but realizing that it's the view that you're interested in may point you to the answer.

Comment: Correct, that's the solution! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i get the position of a modal UINavigationController on the iPad-Screen? I tried .view.frame, but i always get the coordinates 0,0.

An app's root view controller generally fills the app's entire window, and it's frame is expressed in the coordinate system of its superview, which is the window. For that reason, it's not surprising that the origin of the frame rectangle is at (0,0), since that's the top left corner of the window.

Now, the window normally also fills the screen, and so the window's origin should also be located at (0,0), but it may be different if you're using the app in split screen mode.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to map the view controller's view to screen coordinates using the screen's [coordinate space](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace):

```
UIView *view = myViewController.view;
UIScreen *screen = view.window.screen;
NSPoint location = [view convertPoint:view.frame.origin
                    toCoordinateSpace:screen.fixedCoordinateSpace];
```